# How to add code when count down progress bar is 0?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a count down progress bar...
Now i want when it it's 0 that an element is display inline(in css it is display none)

this is my code for the progress bar

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
$element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconden te gaan");
if(timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
}
};

progress(180, 180, $('#progressBar'));
```

can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to display `inline` and what don't you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
$element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(timeleft + " seconden te gaan");
if(timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
}
else
{
     // display inline
     $('#IDofElement').css('display', 'inline');
}
};

progress(180, 180, $('#progressBar'));
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wfu7cdd4/ here is the jsfiddle, i have tried but is doensn't work

Comment: Works for me.  You have the timer set to 180 seconds.  Try lowering to something like 5: progress(5, 5, $('#progressBar'));

Comment: You also have no html markup for your progress bar, but that's another issue.  The element does display inline when the timer is complete.

Comment: See updated jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/wfu7cdd4/5/  I added missing progress bar html based on the css styles you created for it.

Comment: i think something goes wrong because it still don't work in my code

Comment: Are you saying the fiddle link I provided does not work for you?  Or are you saying when you paste it into your main code, then it no longer works?